# angular library install peer dependency problem

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, peer

Every time I am trying to install an angular library using npm (for example I need this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pinch-zoom ), I get a couple of warnings saying that I should install peer dependencies myself.

```
 npm WARN @progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap@2.6.2 requires a peer of bootstrap@git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#95f37e4c402df37db16781995ffa1592032df9c8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN ngx-pinch-zoom@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN ngx-pinch-zoom@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I have tried to downgrade the npm to a version less than 3, but I get the same thing:
    npm install npm@2.8.4

```
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN @progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap@2.6.2 requires a peer of bootstrap@git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#95f37e4c402df37db16781995ffa1592032df9c8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ npm@2.8.4
added 469 packages from 498 contributors, removed 230 packages, updated 29 packages and audited 5980 packages in 62.539s
found 226 vulnerabilities (66 low, 106 moderate, 51 high, 3 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

> npm -v
>       6.5.0

And after that, the version is still 6.5.0. What could be the solution?

Comment: What angular version are you using? Most likely `ngx-pinch-zoom` hasn't been updated to 7 if you are using angular 7.

Comment: I am using Angular 4

Comment: Then there's your issue, it requires angular 6 as it states on the `NPM WARN` --> `requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0-rc.0`

Comment: @penleychan then how to peer install @angular/cpmmon@^6.0.0-rc.0? which command to run? can you please give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The automatic install of peer dependencies was explicitly removed with npm 3, as it causes more problems than it tried to solve. You can read about it here for example:

https://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0

So no, you cannot install peer dependencies automatically with npm 3 upwards.

You can use project `npm-install-peers` to detect and install peers. For using this run `npm install -g npm-install-peers` and then in the project directory run `npm-install-peers`. This will read out your `package.json` file and install all of it's `peerDependencies`.

As of v1.0.1 it doesn't support writing back to the package.json automatically, which would essentially solve our need here.

You can also try  `npm cache clean --f`, `npm install` to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I run npm-install-peers in command line on MAC but shows the error "-bash: npm-install-peers: command not found". I saw the links you provided in the answer but it doesn't provide details about how to answer OP's question. Could you please more details? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYou: run `npm install -g npm-install-peers` and then in the project directory run `npm-install-peers`. This will read out your package.json file and install all of it's `peerDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating npm worked for me.

```
npm install npm -g
```

Reference : https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/1381